# Necesito que un textbox no me deje escribir numeros

Tags: asp.net

tengo un textbox en el webform en asp.net (sin MVC), necesito que únicamente deje escribir letras

Comment: Hazlo con `javascript`

Comment: como? no se porque soy nuevo en esto de programar :(

Comment: Ya te coloco la respuesta.

Comment: gracias amigo ;)

Comment: Hazlo a traves de la tabla ASCII, definiendo el rango que excluya a los numeros

Comment: [Te pueden votar negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es crear tu `JavaScript` donde indiques mediante una expresión regular que solo debes admitir letras, en caso contrario cancelas el `evento` que desencadenas cuando pulsas una tecla:

```
function SoloLetras(e) {
    if (!(/[A-Za-z]/.test(e.key)))
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

Agregar el `TextBox` al formulario web:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Y en el `CodeBehind` agregas el atributo a ese control de esta manera, lo que se realiza aquí es que envías el evento cada vez que pulsas una tecla a la función de `JavaScript`:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "SoloLetras(event);");
```

También tienes esta manera, lo que se hace es que te retorna un `bool` en la función cada vez que cumpla con la condición del `Regex` si es una letra te devolverá `true` y permitirá la entrada del texto:

```
function SoloLetras(e) {
    return (/[A-Za-z]/.test(e.key));
}
```

Y así en el `CodeBehind`:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return SoloLetras(event);");
```

[Documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp/test) acerca del uso del `.test` y una expresión regular.